# Gulp - migrate from node-sass to sass for Angular.JS

Tags: node.js, angularjs, sass, gulp, node-sass

we have an Angular.JS project and we using Gulp.

I am trying to get out of `node-sass` as its deprecated to dart `sass`

is angular.js compatible with sass

Node version : 15

here how we are using the node-sass

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var paths = gulp.paths;
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

// TODO: node-sass is deprecated; replace with
// dart-sass (https://sass-lang.com/dart-sass)
$.sass.compiler = require('node-sass');

gulp.task('styles', function () {

  var injectFiles = gulp.src([
    paths.src + '/{app,components}/**/*.scss',
    '!' + paths.src + '/app/index.scss',
    '!' + paths.src + '/app/vendor.scss'
  ], { read: false });

  var injectOptions = {
    transform: function(filePath) {
      filePath = filePath.replace(paths.src + '/app/', '');
      filePath = filePath.replace(paths.src + '/components/', '../components/');
      return '@import \'' + filePath + '\';';
    },
    starttag: '// injector',
    endtag: '// endinjector',
    addRootSlash: false
  };

  // "Enables you to work on a subset of the original files by filtering them
  // using glob patterns. When you're done and want all the original files back,
  // you just use the restore stream"
  var indexFilter = $.filter(paths.src + '/app/index.scss', {restore: true});

  return gulp.src([
      paths.src + '/app/index.scss', // A template, empty except for the injection target
      paths.src + '/app/vendor.scss' // Currently not used
    ], {allowEmpty: true})
    .pipe(indexFilter)
    .pipe($.inject(injectFiles, injectOptions)) // injects the @import's to all app and component scss
    .pipe(indexFilter.restore)
    .pipe($.sass().on('error', $.sass.logError)) // compiles index.scss (and vendor.scss if existent)
    .pipe($.autoprefixer()
      .on('error', function handleError(err) {
        console.error(err.toString());
        this.emit('end');
      })
    )
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.tmp + '/serve/app/'));
});
```

my tries to migrate

remove `node-sass` and install `sass`
then replace the the compiler with sass

```
$.sass.compiler = require('sass');
```

app is not building anymore

Answer (score 0):

I figure how to make it

replace

```
var sass = require('gulp-sass'));
var compiler = require('sass');
sass.compiler = compiler;
```

with

```
 var sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
```

to be like this in my case

```
....
.pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use use the `postRequireTransforms` property to configure `gulp-sass` to use `dart-sass` (called `sass` in npm).

Change:

```js
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
```

to

```js
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')({
  postRequireTransforms: {
    // Use dart-sass as the compiler for gulp-sass.
    sass: function(gulpSass) {
      return gulpSass(require('sass'));
    }
  }
});
```

Then can use the plugin property `sass()` as usual. `$.sass()`.